# Object level variables when using TypeScript and Vuejs together?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm not sure what the best approach is for this. Pretty much I want to make a component, and I have some object level variables I want to utilize. See the below example:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import * as paper from "paper"

export default Vue.extend({

    template: `
        <div class="chart-container" ref="chart-container">
            <canvas ref="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
    `,

    mounted: function() {

        this.$nextTick(function() {
            let canvas = this.$refs["canvas"] as HTMLCanvasElement
            let chartContainer = this.$refs["chart-container"] as HTMLDivElement
            // Obviously errors out as there is no definition for the variable paperScope
            this.paperScope = new paper.PaperScope()
            this.paperScope.setup(canvas)
        })
    },

    methods: {
        resizeCanvas(): void {
            let chartContainer = this.$refs["chart-container"] as HTMLDivElement
            let width = chartContainer.clientWidth - 30;
            let height = chartContainer.clientHeight - 30;
            // Want to access the class level variable in declared methods
            this.paperScope.view.viewSize = new paper.Size(width, height)
        }
    }
})
```

I'd like to have an object level variable paperScope so I can reference it across methods. I don't want to store these variables in data, as they do not need to be monitored by vuejs. Is there anything like

```
this.$privateVariables["paperScope"] = paperScope
```

that can be used?

My only thought right now is that I'll need to create a type definition that extends the vue one, and includes something like $privateVariables. Just wondering if there is a built-in or better way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

> I don't want to store these variables in data, as they do not need to be monitored by vuejs.

If you want to achieve that kind of non-reactive variables, you can use `$options` to store them. I was also learned this technique from [this issue comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1988#issuecomment-354144340).

https://jsfiddle.net/ujd1h586/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <button @click="updateText">
    update
  </button>
</div>
```

Vue component:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  privateVariable: 'Thanks Vue.js!',

  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    };
  },

  methods: {
    updateText() {
      this.message = this.$options.privateVariable;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the question of using Vue with TypeScript. When using JS, root level properties are stored in $options, but when using TypeScript they're stored in data, making them reactive. It isn't obvious how to make sure properties end up in $options when using TS.